# Open Api v3/api-docs not contains its all variables

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

i have a springboot project working with 2.5.14 version.
I migrate my Swagger 2 to Swagger Open Api but i got some errors.

While upgrading instead of using springfox, i removed them and started to use springdoc-openapi-ui

Here is before and after pom changes

```
 Before:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
After:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I first used 1.3.4 version but it generates InlineObject for some controllers' path variables. Then i started to use 1.7.0 because version 1.6.3 and upper ones not have this problem.

In generated api-doc some objects not contains all of their variables. As an example:

```
@Data
public class BaseRequest implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private UserDto userDto;
  private Long logId;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class ServiceBasedProcessRequest extends BaseRequest {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String name;
  private ProcessCode processCode;
  private String drgCode;
  private DoctorInfo doctorInfo;
  private BigDecimal amountRequest;
  private Date processDateTime;
  private DetailDto detail;
  private String orderNo;
  private BigDecimal rateVat;
  private String rightLeft;
  private Note explanation;
  private Integer count;
  private String swiftCode;
  
  private DoctorDto enrichedDoctorDto;
  private CurrencyType currencyType;
  private Boolean isNew;
  
  private List<ParameterTypeDto> parameterList;
}
```

In the Open api generated document ServiceBasedProcessRequest Object Json doesn't contains **userDto, logId, swiftCode, enrichedDoctorDto, currencyType, isNew, parameterList**

Swagger 2 - /v2/api-docs:

```
"ServiceBasedProcessRequest":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "amountRequest":{
               "type":"number"
            },
            "count":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int64"
            },
            "detail":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/DetailDto"
            },
            "doctorInfo":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/DoctorInfo"
            },
            "drgCode":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "enrichedDoctorDto":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/DoctorDto"
            },
            "explanation":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/Note"
            },
            "isNew":{
               "type":"boolean"
            },
            "logId":{
               "type":"integer",
               "format":"int64"
            },
            "currencyType":{
               "type":"string",
               "enum":[
                  "USD",
                  "EUR",
                  "TL"
               ]
            },
            "name":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "orderNo":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "parameterList":{
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/ParameterTypeDto"
               }
            },
            "processCode":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/ProcessCode"
            },
            "processDateTime":{
               "type":"string",
               "format":"date-time"
            },
            "rateVat":{
               "type":"number"
            },
            "rightLeft":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "swiftCode":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "userDto":{
               "$ref":"#/definitions/UserDto"
            }
         },
         "title":"ServiceBasedProcessRequest"
      }
```

Open Api - /v3/api-docs::

```
"ServiceBasedProcessRequest":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "amountRequest":{
                  "type":"number"
               },
               "count":{
                  "type":"integer",
                  "format":"int64"
               },
               "detail":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/DetailDto"
               },
               "doctorInfo":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/DoctorInfo"
               },
               "drgCode":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "explanation":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Note"
               },
               "name":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "orderNo":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "processCode":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/ProcessCode"
               },
               "processDateTime":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "format":"date-time"
               },
               "rateVat":{
                  "type":"number"
               },
               "rightLeft":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "swiftCode":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
```

Yaml configs:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    docExpansion: none
    displayRequestDuration: true
    deepLinking: true
    showExtensions: true
    operationsSorter: alpha
    tagsSorter: alpha
  cache:
    disabled: true
  writer-with-order-by-keys: true
```

I did tried to add @Schema but i still didn't generate them.
Is there an any configuration for this problem ?